# Not receiving past messages on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Recently I've ported my number from Idea to Vodafone, after doing this and reinstalling WhatsApp after a couple of months I've been removed from all the groups and am not receiving any messages. How do i get bach the messages of the past month?

Answer (score 0):

You can decypt the .cyrpt12 file which will output a .db file which can be viewed easily using a SQLite viewer.